# Using AccessController to limit permissions

Tags: java, security

I'm trying to prevent plugins that run "inside" the main Java application from accessing things they shouldn't. I've read about Policies, and AccessControllers, and ProtectionDomains, but they're very oriented around JARs.

I've tried this:

```
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.security.*


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Policy.setPolicy(object : Policy() {})
    System.setSecurityManager(SecurityManager())

    val domain = ProtectionDomain(null, Permissions() /* no permissions */)
    AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction {
        untrusted()
    }, AccessControlContext(arrayOf(domain)))
}

fun untrusted() {
    try {
        // Works as expected
        Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("build.gradle"))
        throw IllegalStateException("Was able to access file, but shouldn't have been able to")
    } catch (e: AccessControlException) {
    }
    try {
        // Should throw AccessControlException, but doesn't
        AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction {
            Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("build.gradle"))
        })
        throw IllegalStateException("Was able to access file, but shouldn't have been able to")
    } catch (e: AccessControlException) {
    }
}
```

Even though I'm invoking `untrusted()` via a custom limited `ProtectionDomain`, it seems it can trivially break out of it. I'm expecting the the `doPrivileged` call in `untrusted` to operate with the intersection of the permissions of the outermost `ProtectionDomain` (the main program, which has all permissions) and the caller's `ProtectionDomain` (which has no permissions), resulting in `untrusted` having essentially 0 permissions.

---

I've also tried with the domain set like this:

```
val domain = ProtectionDomain(CodeSource(URL("http://foo"), null as Array<CodeSigner>?), Permissions() /* no permissions */)
```

but this also doesn't work -- the `Policy` is queried with the main program's `ProtectionDomain` and not the one calling `untrusted()`. (Obviously I'd need to update the `Policy` to handle "http://foo" correctly, but it doesn't even check that `ProtectionDomain` anyway)

---

So where has my understanding gone wrong?

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research on this, I think I have an answer. I could write a significantly *longer* answer, but I think I'll just cut to the chase here.

Each class loaded by a ClassLoader has a [ProtectionDomain](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html)+[CodeSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/CodeSource.html) associated with it. These are somewhat coarse -- a CodeSource represents where a class came from, but it's not a pointer to an individual `.class` file or anything -- it's to a directory or a JAR. Thus two classes in the same JAR or directory will generally have identical permissions. Any class or script that has an identifiable ProtectionDomain+CodeSource can be whitelisted/blacklisted by your Policy.

The exception (kinda) to this is, of course, is [AccessController.doPrivileged](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#doPrivileged-java.security.PrivilegedAction-java.security.AccessControlContext-java.security.Permission...-) with Permission arguments. This lets you clamp down the permissions of a region of code. But *that* code could, in theory, call `AccessController.doPrivileged` with just the callback. That method signature means "don't check my entire call stack for permissions; just look up my ProtectionDomain+CodeSource in the Policy file and see what it says." So if you're running truly untrusted code, you better make sure that a. it has a ProtectionDomain+CodeSource different from your trusted application, and b. that your Policy is able to identify that code and grant it appropriately-limited permissions.

Comment: ...and since a custom domain can choose not to delegate to policy but self-assert its privileges, it is essential that the class loader performing the untrusted-class-to-domain mapping also be under trusted code's control. The default security manager offers an intimidating degree of flexibility -- access control context (effective or fake) -> domains (set by class loader, custom ACC, or custom domain combiner) (-> policy (-> permission collection / permission / code source / principal)) -- no wonder many prefer the deceptively simpler route of replacing the default implementation altogether.

Comment: By the way, a code source can "point" at anything, tangible or intangible (provided a `URLStreamHandler` is available for the chosen URL scheme, and whatever component, e.g. policy, tasked with processing it can comprehend). That includes individual .class files. My guess on why the default JDK class loader implementations don't offer this kind of granularity is because it could potentially interfere with the concern of code *accessibility*, which the designers of the security framework have chosen to keep orthogonal to authorization.

Comment: Indeed my original attempt to sandbox plugins coming from the same JAR as my app involved manually loading those classes from a custom classloader that would then give each class a "plugin://something"-type code domain, but this turned out to be a bit hairier than I was expecting. I've shied away from the domain combiner stuff as well due to not needing it yet and perceived complexity. I've read you're really not *supposed* to replace the default SecurityManager, so...I haven't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way for the example to run as intended, i.e., to effectively blacklist subsequent execution paths under the same domain. The core permission-intersection-based authorization model should still hold. The sample must be run with `-Djava.system.class.loader=com.example.Test$AppClassLoader` (this replacement system class loader is only needed in order to attain a working single-file example).

Obligatory disclaimer: While technically many things are possible, to the point of dynamically white-/blacklisting individual instances and beyond, they all involve additional context of some sort being introduced into the already non-trivial authorization process. Such approaches should be avoided whenever possible. The proper solution, sufficing in the vast majority of cases, as documented in the OP's [answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50079083/3986374) conclusion, is to package trusted code separately from untrusted (and, when manually managing class-to-domain mappings, ensuring that code bases of distinct trustworthiness are mapped to distinct domains), and assign appropriate permissions to the resulting domains.

```
package com.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.AccessControlException;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.AllPermission;
import java.security.CodeSource;
import java.security.Permission;
import java.security.PermissionCollection;
import java.security.Permissions;
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static final class AppClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

        private static final URL[] CLASS_PATH;
        private static final String SANDBOXABLE_DOMAIN_CLASS_NAME = "com.example.Test$SandboxableDomain";

        static {
            String[] paths = System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(File.pathSeparator);
            List<URL> classPath = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String path : paths) {
                try {
                    classPath.add(new URL("file://" + path));
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException ex) {}
            }
            CLASS_PATH = classPath.toArray(new URL[0]);
        }

        private final Constructor<?> sandboxableDomainCtor;

        {
            try {
                // ensure this loader defines SandboxableDomain so that normal code
                // can safely / conveniently access it via class literal
                Class<?> sandboxableDomainClass = loadClass(SANDBOXABLE_DOMAIN_CLASS_NAME, true);
                sandboxableDomainCtor = sandboxableDomainClass.getConstructor(CodeSource.class,
                        PermissionCollection.class, ClassLoader.class);
            }
            catch (ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }

        public AppClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
            super(CLASS_PATH, parent);
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            if (name.startsWith("java") || name.startsWith("sun")) {
                return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
            }
            Class<?> ret = findLoadedClass(name);
            if (ret != null) {
                return ret;
            }
            ProtectionDomain assignedDomain;
            byte[] classData;
            try {
                URL classResource = getResource(name.replace(".", "/") + ".class");
                CodeSource assignedCodeSource = new CodeSource(classResource, (Certificate[]) null);
                classData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(classResource.toURI()));
                if (SANDBOXABLE_DOMAIN_CLASS_NAME.equals(name)) {
                    // loading the domain class itself; ensure _its own_ domain is fully privileged,
                    // so that it doesn't affect authorization
                    PermissionCollection perms = new Permissions();
                    perms.add(new AllPermission());
                    assignedDomain = new ProtectionDomain(assignedCodeSource, perms, this, null);
                }
                else {
                    // the per-class code source (URL) is unintentional; normally all classes under
                    // the same class path entry would share one
                    assignedDomain = (ProtectionDomain) sandboxableDomainCtor.newInstance(assignedCodeSource,
                            getPermissions(assignedCodeSource), this);
                }
            }
            catch (NullPointerException | URISyntaxException | IOException | ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
                throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
            }
            ret = defineClass(name, classData, 0, classData.length, assignedDomain);
            if (resolve) {
                resolveClass(ret);
            }
            return ret;
        }

    }

    public static final class SandboxableDomain extends ProtectionDomain {

        private static final Permission DO_SANDBOXED_PERM = new RuntimePermission("com.example.doSandboxed");

        private final ThreadLocal<Boolean> sandboxed = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();

        public SandboxableDomain(CodeSource cs, PermissionCollection permissions, ClassLoader classLoader) {
            super(cs, permissions, classLoader, null);
            sandboxed.set(false);
        }

        // no equivalent doUnsandboxed here for escaping the sandbox on-demand;
        // firstly because it's fishy; secondly because it would be impossible
        // to distinguish a privileged caller based on permissions alone
        public void doSandboxed(Runnable action) {
            if (!sandboxed.get()) {
                SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
                if (sm != null) {
                    sm.checkPermission(DO_SANDBOXED_PERM);
                }
            }
            sandboxed.set(true);
            try {
                action.run();
            }
            finally {
                sandboxed.set(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean implies(Permission permission) {
            if (sandboxed.get()) {
                // static only (AppClassLoader only grants essentials like reading from own directory)
                PermissionCollection perms = getPermissions();
                return (perms == null) ? false : perms.implies(permission);
            }
            // static + policy
            return super.implies(permission);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        initSecurity();
        SandboxableDomain ownDomain = (SandboxableDomain) Test.class.getProtectionDomain();

        System.out.println("Try unsandboxed"); // should succeed
        untrusted();

        System.out.println("---\n\nTry sandboxed"); // should fail
        ownDomain.doSandboxed(Test::untrusted);

        System.out.println("---\n\nTry unsandboxed from within a child thread"); // should succeed
        new Thread(Test::untrusted).start();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        System.out.println("---\n\nTry unsandboxed from within a sandboxed child thread"); // should fail
        ownDomain.doSandboxed(() -> new Thread(Test::untrusted).start());

    }

    private static void initSecurity() throws Exception {
        Path tempPolicyConfig = Files.createTempFile(null, null);
        // self-grant AllPermission
        Files.write(tempPolicyConfig,
                Collections.singletonList(new StringBuilder("grant codebase \"")
                        .append(Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()).append("\"{permission ")
                        .append(AllPermission.class.getName()).append(";};").toString()));
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "=" + tempPolicyConfig.toString());
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        Files.delete(tempPolicyConfig);
    }

    private static void untrusted() {
        try {
            untrusted0();
            System.out.println("\tSucceeded");
        }
        catch (AccessControlException ex) {
            System.out.println("\tFailed; try via doPrivileged");
            try {
                AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction<Void>) () -> {
                    untrusted0();
                    return null;
                });
                System.out.println("\t\tSucceeded");
            }
            catch (AccessControlException ex1) {
                System.out.println("\t\tFailed anew");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void untrusted0() {
        try {
            Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("build.gradle"));
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```