# Is it possible to sandbox just a Runnable

Tags: java, sandbox, java-security-manager

Is it possible to sandbox my Runnable within Java? Given a Runnable, I want the code inside of it (along with whatever threads it spawns) to run in a sandbox that only lets the code access a specific path on the fileystem. Once that Runnable finishes, the thread should go back to whatever normal permissions it had while any remaining spawned threads would still have the filesystem restriction applied.

I want to do this at run-time. That means that I want to avoid creating policy files and passing in custom arguments to the JVM. I've so far been able to apply sandboxing to my entire application but I haven't found a way to scope it to just the Runnable running in the current thread...

```
if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
}

CodeSource nullSource = new CodeSource(null, (CodeSigner[]) null);

PermissionCollection perms = new Permissions();
perms.add(new FilePermission(path.toAbsolutePath().toString() + "/*", "read"));

ProtectionDomain domain = new ProtectionDomain(nullSource, perms);
AccessControlContext safeContext = new AccessControlContext(
        new ProtectionDomain[]{domain});

AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction) () -> {
    try {
        r.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    return null;
}, safeContext);
```

Comment: The canonical way of doing authorization is by assigning permissions to *code*, not threads. The assignment may still be dynamic (one may always reload the policy at runtime, or use a handcrafted mutable one), but always thread-independent. Nonetheless, there are (ugly) workarounds -- as shown e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50220239/3986374).

Answer (score 3):

The `doPrivileged` technique of limiting permissions applies only to trusted code that does not abuse its position (for instance, by calling `doPrivileged` itself). So useful as a layer against XML inclusion, for instance, but not untrusted plugins.

You can load code at runtime with specific permissions using a custom `ClassLoader`, but you would have to reload the code if you wanted the permissions.

The *Object Capability Model* gives a 'pure' dynamic solution. The container passes the plugin *an object* that is capable of performing the privileged action. Internally the object's methods can just be the action surrounded by a `doPrivileged`. Crucially the actions are only available through an instance and unprivileged code is not permitted to instantiate it. This is similar to, say, `FileOpenService` in JNLP/WebStart, if you ignore `ServiceMangaer`. Internal to the JDK you may see the likes of `Unsafe` and `SharedSecrets`, although those are more about avoiding repeated security checks.